# Google Cloud Centos 7 Image Load Failure - No '/dev/log' or 'logger' included for syslog logging"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, centos, google-compute-engine

I am trying to import a Centos 7 virtual Disk using :

gcloud compute images import import1  --source-file gs://my-image/disk1.vmdk --os centos-7

but I am getting an error that the /dev/log is not there:
...

*[import-and-translate]: 2019-01-27T10:35:02Z Error running workflow: step "translate" run error: step "translate-disk" run error: step "wait-for-translator" run error: WaitForInstancesSignal FailureMatch found for "inst-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-3lzlh": "TranslateFailed: error: command: No '/dev/log' or 'logger' included for syslog logging"
[import-and-translate]: 2019-01-27T10:35:02Z Workflow "import-and-translate" cleaning up (this may take up to 2 minutes).
[Daisy] Errors in one or more workflows:
  import-and-translate: step "translate" run error: step "translate-disk" run error: step "wait-for-translator" run error: WaitForInstancesSignal FailureMatch found for "inst-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-3lzlh": "TranslateFailed: error: command: **No '/dev/log' or 'logger' included for syslog logging"**
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/compute-image-tools/daisy:release" failed: exit status 1
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.images.import) build c23b5b7a-81e4-47ea-a95d-6a531d823165 completed with status "FAILURE"*

I have the same image runnning in a VirtualBox and /dev/log is there:

[deploy@localhost deploy]$ ls -lrt /dev/log

srw-rw-rw- 1 root root 0 Jan 28 14:02 /dev/log

Answer (score 1):

you'd have to prepare the import; see the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/import-existing-image).

also, configure the VM after the import; some more [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/configuring-imported-images#install_guest_environment).

using a working image with a [startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) is probably less effort.

Comment: Thanks!!. I tried https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/import-existing-image.  the import worked however it only replicated the file system structure but not the /home/user structure its content and the apps installed there.

Then, I had to create a new Centos VM instance and install all the packages and application "manually".

Comment: @Pablo that's what startup scripts are made for. for a single instance the "manual approach" still might suffice; but not when setting up a whole bunch of instances. this is also good for documenting setups, so that they can be reproduced at any given time; and one can even load them directly from a bucket.